# Get subclass name python

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, oop

I have 2 built-in classes in library.

```
class Main:
# some code
def __repr__(self):
    #here i should return class where it was called

class MainGroup:
# some code

class Form(MainGroup):
   name = Main()
```

Now, I need to get 'Form' - name of a class. I should get it when I call Form.name . I thought of creating __ repr __ function, but the problem is, I need to get class name, where Main() is called.

Output should be:

```
print(Form.name)
Output: 'Form'
```

But I am not sure how to get 'Form' output from a class called in my Form class.

Comment: Can you please explain what do you try to do?

Comment: I edited the Main function. It should have __repr__ function, which should return __class__.__name__ of a class where it was called. But I am not sure how to get class name where the class instance was created

Comment: To get access to the instance from an attribute, you’ll want to look at the *descriptor protocol*. See the duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classes and functions have a `__name__` attribute just for storing the definition name as a string: `Form.__name__` is `"Form"`.

You can't really make a class attribute reference its own class in the definition, but you can do this:

```
class Form:
    pass

Form.name = Form.__name__
```

Comment: But i need to get name from Form.name, any ideas?

Comment: I do, it's a little tricky so I'll amend the post

Comment: I tried Form.name.__class__.__name__, it says my class Name is 'Main'

Comment: There's a better way to get `name` to print out `"Form"`, check my edit

Comment: Then do you have any idea how to get class name in Main, I called Main class in Form.name? i will set class name as attribute in Main, then I will access it

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. Maybe if you amend your post to clearly state what inputs and outputs you want. For example, you said you wanted `Form.name` to result in `"Form"`. Give more examples of what you want with `Main`.